# Threaded UDP server bug

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

I've broken this code somehow and I can't fix it. The server/client code was written by someone else (mostly from the examples in py manuals), and I can't work out what's wrong.

I'm getting issues with super and init and that jazz, mostly because I don't fully understand and find most documentation on the subject leaves me more confused than when I started. For now, I'll be happy enough to get it working. It's likely to be some silly issue, fixed in one line.

Any ideas? I've tried not to paste in code not relevant, but I can add more or provide the whole file if it helps. The code falls over specifically when a handle thread is created. My test case is running code instances, and passing messages between them and it falls over on receipt of the first UDP message.

```
# Library imports
import threading
import SocketServer
import multiprocessing

# .. More code here ...

class ThreadedUDPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.UDPServer):
    pass


class NodeDaemon(ThreadedUDPServer):
    def __init__(self, host, port, modules):
        ThreadedUDPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), NodeProtocolHandler)

        # Store parameters in the class
        self.modules    = modules
        self.port       = port
        self.ip         = host

        # Check if we have enabled multithreaded listen daemon
        if settings.MULTI:
            self.server_thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.serve_forever)
        else:
            self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.serve_forever)

        # Make the server thread daemonic
        self.server_thread.daemon = True

        # Start the server thread
        self.server_thread.start()

        # Update our identity node info
        self.modules.identity = NodeInfo(host, port)

    def fetch_modules(self):
        return self.modules


class NodeProtocolHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
        Handles nody things.
        Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html
        For more sweet deets.
    """
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler,self).__init__(args,kwargs)

        # Grab modules references
        self.modules = self.server.fetch_modules()


        # ... More code here .. #

    def handle(self):
        """
            Main routine to handle all incoming UDP packets.
        """
        # Grab the raw message data received
        raw_data = self.request[0].strip()

        # ... More code here ...
```

The error generated is:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60377)
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\some_dir\node_daemon.py", line 60, in __init__
    super(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler,self).__init__(args,kwargs)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
-        super(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler,self).__init__(args, kwargs)
+        SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
```